# How to make a http call to dockerized express server from index.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, web

I don't understand how I can make http call from index.html to express server which serves that index.html and is located inside docker container.

```
index.html:
<script type="text/javascript">
      var getAppId = new XMLHttpRequest();
      getAppId.open("GET", "/appId", false);
      getAppId.send(null);
</script>
```

I need that http call to get know the app id which is presented by docker env variable. That call must be listened in server.js (express.js) :

```
router.get("/appId",(req,res) => {
  res.send({applicationId : process.env.APP_ID});
});
```

But when I run my dockerized app I see that my http call receives **404 http code.** 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use fetch:

```
fetch('www.example.com/appId', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}
}).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
    }).then(function(res){
        if(res){
           doSomesthing();
        }
        else{
            console.log('yourError')
        }
    }).catch((e)=>{console.log(e)})
```

But 404 means the route is not found. Are you sure it's everything set up correctly on your server?

Comment: Yes, I am totally sure that everything set up correctly. I think problem is that docker app has domen name e.g. https://www.test.com and behind this domen name  express exists. And problem that index.html make a call to domen name but not to express. Don't know how to redirect call directly to express

Comment: and in fetch you also you have to write the full route including domain www.example.com/appId

Comment: One more thing, make sure your docker container listens to port 80.

Comment: Why I have to write path with domen name if the browser automatically places the domain name to path I request?  E.g fetch("/appId") in the browser call will be transformed to https://www.exmaple.com/appId .

Comment: @chary1212 My docker runs on 8085

Comment: @Self_taught. How should "/appId" get transformed automatically to "exmaple.com/appId" ?  "/appId" is a const string and will not get converted. And if your docker exposes port 8085 it can not get your requests, because the browser automatically requests on port 80. You have to map port 80 of express to port 80 on your host. And if you're using ssl you probably wanna setup a reverse proxy server before your docker container listening on port 443. In this case you can leave your docker port as it is, but make sure forwarding works from 443-->8050->express port (e.g. 80)

Comment: tnx you for your answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question please :) What if I don't know domen name beforehand ? I mean that I can have two or more nodes with the same Vue application but which are hosted on a different nodes with different domen names

Comment: you can also work without domains but only with ip, that won't work with ssl though. if server and client is on the same machine you can also work with "localhost/appId" instead of domain name or ip. either you use the "ip/appId" or "domain/appId" or "localhost/appId"